IJCADでESCキーが効かなくなる
IJCAD 2023にMicrosoft .NET Framework Version 4.8を使用して作成したカスタマイズPGをロードした環境で、作図中、「ESC」キーが、度々利かなくなります。
（そのまま再立ち上げしないと治らない）
［ESC］が効かなくなるのは、カスタマイズコマンドに限らず、IJCAD標準コマンドでも発生します。
この状態でも右クリック長押しからの「キャンセル」は使える場合がありますが、こちらも使えない場合もあります。
また［Delete］など他のキーも効かなくなることがあります。
再現する規則性が不明で、敢えて言えば長時間起動している場合かも知れません。
同様の事例や対処法があれば教えてください。
